# Hudson Mail Server Not Working

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I've verified my AuthSmtp Settings. I'm sure everything is given in perfectly. Unable to identify reason behind why it's not able to send mail.

I get this exception after all my tests are run and Hudson tries to send mails

```
ERROR: Unknown SMTP host: mail.authsmtp.com
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: mail.authsmtp.com;
nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.authsmtp.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1932)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.send(Mailer.java:509)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.send(Mailer.java:476)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:91)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:112)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:34)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:646)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:624)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:600)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1414)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.authsmtp.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:175)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:385)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
... 16 more
```

[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: feature-mentoring-connections-v2 #102
Finished: SUCCESS

what could've possibly gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the server "mail.authsmtp.com"

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.authsmtp.com
```

- is this a valid URL? (can you ping it)
- Can jenkins ping this URL (create a testjob that does a ping for you)
- Is there a firewall issue?

Comment: yes, It's valid URL. Yes Jenkins Can I am able to send in test mails. There's no firewall issue.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are able to send test mails through Jenkins?

Comment: I am joining the I-am-out-of-ideas club now.